# Merge Error occurred while Deliver Baselines to Alternative Target

Tags: windows-10, clearcase

We are having some problems while trying to deliver some files in Clearcase .
3 out of 4  files fail with this error:

Error Messages:

> An error occurred during the Deliver operation.
>
> An error occurred while merging file elements in the target view.
>   Unable to perform merge.
>   Unable to do integration.

This happens after a windows workstation upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10, but we are not sure that it's related . We are using a version 8.0.1 CC client. We tried to update the view but this didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least to do a `cleartool status` in the merge destination view, in the parent folder of those failed files.

Either the status can give you a clue, or there is another OS-related reason, like typically a Windows process keeping an handle on the file which should be modified by the merge, preventing (locking) said modification.

Also, check your environment variable, like `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` to ensure that was not lost during the workstation OS upgrade.
That would be reflected in the properties of the view:

```
cd /path/to/view/used/for/merge
cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview
```

> We tried to update the view but this didn't solve the issue.

"update" means snapshot view.
Nothing prevent to reset/retry your merge using a brand new *dynamic* view: that would avoid any OS-lock issue.